# Incompatible padding mode when decyrpt usiing Cipher with instance "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"

Tags: android, kotlin, encryption-asymmetric

I had this problem when trying to decrypt an encrypted string. I had read a lot and also search for answers from Stack Overflow, but nothing works. You can see code I attach, it's not complex but the problem makes me confused. I'm using Kotlin, and yes, it's for Android.

```
     private fun generateKeyPair() {
        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEYSTORE)
        keyStore.load(null)
        if (keyStore.containsAlias(keyAlias)) return
        val keyGenerator =
            KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, ANDROID_KEYSTORE)
        val builder = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
            keyAlias,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
        )
            .setKeySize(4096)
            .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
            .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(true)
            .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)

        keyGenerator.initialize(builder.build(), SecureRandom())
        keyGenerator.generateKeyPair()

    }

    fun encryptApplicationKey(
        data: String
    ) {
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getPublicKey())
        val encryptResult = cipher.doFinal(data.toByteArray())
        val encryptResultString = Base64.encodeToString(encryptResult, Base64.DEFAULT)
        text_view_info.text = encryptResultString
    }

    fun decryptApplicationKey(data: String) {
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getPrivateKey()) //it throw Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Incompatible padding mode
        val encryptedData = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT)
        val decryptResult = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData)
        val decryptResultString = String(decryptResult)
        text_view_info.text = decryptResultString
    }

    fun getPublicKey(): PublicKey {
        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEYSTORE)
        keyStore.load(null)
        val publicKey = keyStore.getCertificate(keyAlias).publicKey
        val unrestrictedPublicKey: PublicKey =
            KeyFactory.getInstance(publicKey.algorithm).generatePublic(
                X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey.encoded)
            )
        return unrestrictedPublicKey
    }

    fun getPrivateKey(): PrivateKey {
        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEYSTORE)
        keyStore.load(null)
        return keyStore.getKey(keyAlias, null) as PrivateKey
    }
```

When I debugged the `getPrivateKey()` function, it's return `AndroidKeyStoreRSAPrivateKey` object. I don't know if the problem related to the usage of PKCS1Padding, but when I'm using OAEP padding, there's no crash when run it.
Does the device affect the result? I have commented where the crash happens.

Comment: Hey, i see that you read other stack answers, but have you checked this?:
"Either the key is wrong or the Base64 encoding is adding stuff if your keys to long. So its seeing mismatched sizes."
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55046705/keystore-operation-failed-incompatible-padding-mode

Comment: I already tried it and still producing the same error. Also, the solution is too hacky and I don't want to do that way. Thanks for the comment btw

Comment: I am also getting this,, were you able to find a solution ?

Comment: I'm playing with KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder, just mix and match until find the best way @ashishdhiman2007